Probability lower bounds
We have three events $A, B, C.$
Also we have, $$\mathcal{P}(A\cap B\cap C)=\mathcal{P}(A)-\mathcal{P}(A\cap(\overline{B}\cup \overline{C})).$$
From above result how can prove that $$\mathcal{P}(A)-\mathcal{P}(A\cap(\overline{B}\cup \overline{C}))\geq \mathcal{P}(A)-\mathcal{P}(A\cap \overline{B})-\mathcal{P}(A\cap \overline{C})?$$

You don't need the equality condition to prove the goal: it is just a corollary of the well-known inequality $P(E_1 \cup E_2) \leq P(E_1) + P(E_2)$.

Hm. Still few needed. But congrats on 20k!

In case anyone is curious, this inequality is sometimes called Boole’s inequality or the union bound.

@mhdadk Thank you for the remark -- I was searching for this name in my head but it returned void :).
